# How do I add a custom script to my package.json file that runs a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, run-script

I want to be able to execute the command `script1` in a project directory that will run `node script1.js`.

`script1.js` is a file in the same directory.  The command needs to be specific to the project directory, meaning that if I send someone else the project folder, they will be able to run the same command.

So far I've tried adding:

```
"scripts": {
    "script1": "node script1.js"
}
```

to my package.json file but when I try running `script1` I get the following output:

```
zsh: command not found: script1
```

Does anyone know the steps necessary to add the script mentioned above to the project folder?

*Note: the command can not be added to the bash profile (cannot be a machine specific command)

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: how are you trying to run it? are you using "npm run script1"?

Comment: did you run script1 using `npm run script1`?

Comment: @Claudiordgz is right, or as in Sujeet's answer, "npm start" and "npm test" are shortcuts for scripts called "start" and "test"

Comment: in my terminal I need to be able to type the one word command called ```script1``` which should run ```node script1.js```

Answer (score 372, accepted):

### Custom Scripts

`npm run-script <custom_script_name>`

*or*

`npm run <custom_script_name>`

In your example, you would want to run `npm run-script script1` or `npm run script1`.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

### Lifecycle Scripts

Node also allows you to run custom scripts for certain lifecycle events, like after `npm install` is run. These can be found [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts).

For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild",
},
```

This would run `electron-rebuild` after a `npm install` command.

Comment: `npm run-script scriptname` worked for me, however `npm run scriptname` didn't!

Comment: How it possible to run a custom script without the "run" command?
Sails.js dose that - it has a command `sails lift` which does even requiring NPM.
Does installing it via NPM add a terminal script on the system where it's installed? If not, how is this made?

Comment: @GalGrünfeld did you install sails globally (npm install -g)?

Comment: I have, and I did some reading, aand as far as can remember from Sail's website, installing it globally (via `-g`), found out that Sails installs bash/cmdlet scripts (e.g `sails generate api <api_name>` (bash/cmdlet according to the machine it's installs on) and adds global paths to those scripts on the machine.

Comment: how to run js file of downloaded npm package through my package.json?

Answer (score 49):

I have created the following, and it's working on my system. Please try this:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node script1.js"   
  }
}
```

script1.js:

```
console.log('testing')
```

From your command line run the following command:

```
npm start
```

**Additional use case**

My package.json file has generally the following scripts, which enable me to watch my files for typescript, sass compilations and running a server as well.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"sass --watch ./style/sass:./style/css\" \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",    
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w", 
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install" 
  }
```

Comment: the command to run the ```script1.js``` file needs to be a custom one word command called ```script1```

Comment: then change `"start"` to `script1`, you can use any name you like, I prefer to use `start` to clearly defined what should run

Comment: @sujeet-jaiswal simply changing from start to script1 is not going to work. The word "start" is reserved in npm, so it works. The word script1 is not and it will not be recognized, even when it is defined in package.json The wesleysmyth answer above is the correct one, just add run to the call.

Comment: No. @SujeetJaiswal is correct. It's in NPM's docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-start

Answer (score 40):

Steps are below:

1. In package.json add:

   ```
   "bin":{
       "script1": "bin/script1.js" 
   }
   ```
2. Create a `bin` folder in the project directory and add file `runScript1.js` with the code:

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env node
   var shell = require("shelljs");
   shell.exec("node step1script.js");
   ```
3. Run `npm install shelljs` in terminal
4. Run `npm link` in terminal
5. From terminal you can now run `script1` which will run `node script1.js`

Reference: http://blog.npmjs.org/post/118810260230/building-a-simple-command-line-tool-with-npm

Comment: This should be the accepted answer based on @Jake.JS comment on his question, i.e. how to run it with a single command.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer based on the question

Answer (score 12):

Lets say in scripts you want to run 2 commands with a single command:

```
"scripts":{
  "start":"any command",
  "singleCommandToRunTwoCommand":"some command here && npm start"
}
```

Now go to your terminal and run there `npm run singleCommandToRunTwoCommand`.

Comment: Whilst helpful, this doesn't directly answer the OP's question.

Comment: Basically we are intended to guide onto the rigth path, more over you do on your own. This is the proper way of learning.

Comment: @AdamJB He does, because he used **npm run <script_name>**

Comment: @kubadev, I don't mean to be pedantic, was just pointing out that the OP requires the script to be run with a one word command as per his own comment on his question: `In my terminal I need to be able to type the one word command called script1 which should run node script1.js`

Answer (score 10):

Suppose I have this line of scripts in my "package.json"

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "export_advertisements": "node export.js advertisements",
    "export_homedata": "node export.js homedata",
    "export_customdata": "node export.js customdata",
    "export_rooms": "node export.js rooms"
  },
```

Now to run the script "export_advertisements", I will simply go to the terminal and type

```
npm run export_advertisements
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i was too stupid and I was running the below command

```
node run build
```

rather than below command

```
npm run build
```

please recheck your command once before cleaning and rerunning install.

Also please don't forget about **npx** which it you can use any module without installing it.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build_c": "ng build --prod && del \"../../server/front-end/*.*\" /s /q & xcopy /s dist \"../../server/front-end\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

As you can see, the script "build_c" is building the angular application, then deletes all old files from a directory, then finally copies the result build files.

Comment: Here's some useful info about `&&` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39172536/running-npm-scripts-sequentially?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa