# How to run node file with custom command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, run-script

I have node file whose name is `author.js` which is present under import folder. How I run this file using the command :  `import author` please help me into this?

Comment: Don't quite understand what your problem is, you might want to reword it a bit. Just incase you are looking for the command for running nodeJS, `node author.js`.

Comment: Put your code in the question. Difficult to help without that!

Comment: I just want to run my node file with the custom command. To run node file we are using `node author.js` but if I want to use the custom command to run node file, My question similar to [How do I add a custom script to my package.json file that runs a javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433461/how-do-i-add-a-custom-script-to-my-package-json-file-that-runs-a-javascript-file) but I can't able to understand please help me into this?

Comment: change environment variable settings to define your custom commands

Comment: I don't really understand your question, maybe you could explain your problem better. Is your question: How can I run my author.js with via command line with the command `import author` instead of `node author.js`? Or is your problem that you don't know how to include author.js into your main.js or app.js or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand this correctly, 
if you are looking to execute certain commands/functions that are in the author.js file via the terminal, the thing you are looking for is argv on the process object for passing in values from the terminal.

So for example in the terminal you type:

```
node author.js import authorName
```

And in your file you have a function that listens to the argv object

```
if(process.argv[2] == 'import'){ 
  /* some function that does stuff with process.argv[3] value (authorName)*/ 
}
```

You would be able to run the function directly from the command line.

For more information on process.argv: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv