# Redis does not start automatically

Tags: javascript, redis

I have a ReactJS web app which uses Redis Database. I'm deploying my system on 2 different computers with Ubuntu 16.04. 
However, I can make the server run with `npm start` in one computer without any errors, but in the other one, when I use `npm start` 
it prompts me with this error:

```
Redis connection to localhost:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED
```

So in order to avoid that error, I need to start Redis manually with `redis-server` , but I don't want to do that. Searched the net for answer but couldn't find a proper solution. So this is my last chance. Thanks for reading ^^

Answer (score 1):

You need to add script to start `redis-server` in your npm start script. Here's sample code -

```
{
  "name": "test app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "sh redis-start-script.sh && **your start script**"   
  }
}
```

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433461/how-do-i-add-a-custom-script-to-my-package-json-file-that-runs-a-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following script,

`"scripts":{ "start": "redis-server --daemonize yes && your start script " }`

It will keep your redis server keeps running