# Create pseudo node_modules folder on npm install

Tags: node.js, angular

I updated some libraries within my project and now I get an issue with the `zlib` within `ng2-pdf-viewer`.
There is also an issue created on github, that helped to fix it for now:
https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer/issues/322#issuecomment-389281242

The solution suggests to create a `zlib` folder within `node_modules` and add an empty `index.js` and a basic `package.json`.

This fixed the issue. But now I want to automate the process, since every time anyone runs `npm install` the pseudo folder is gone again.

Is there any way to create this folder with it's content automatically on `npm install` (maybe with `mkdir` or something)?

PS: The solution to put `"browser": { "zlib": false }` into the `package.json` didn't help in my case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a script to create the directory, and then use a hook to run that script after you run npm install:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "myCustomScriptToCreateFolder",
},
```

More reading:

- [npm Scripts Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)
- [StackOverflow Post about this sort of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433461/how-do-i-add-a-custom-script-to-my-package-json-file-that-runs-a-javascript-file)