# Why can I add script to script in package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

I'm trying to add script to the script's watch in the **package.json** file.
For example, I got:

```
{
"scripts": {
    "delete": "rm -f wwwroot/*.js wwwroot/*.css wwwroot/*.html wwwroot/*.map"
    "watch": "npm run delete; parcel watch Client/index.html --out-dir wwwroot"
  }
}
```

Then when I run `npm run watch`, in the terminal, it throw me this error:

```
> projectName@1.0.0 watch C:\Users\username\userProjectName\path\ProjectName
> npm run delete; parcel watch Client/index.html --out-dir wwwroot

npm ERR! missing script: delete;
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     delete

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-01T17_17_44_173Z-debug.lognpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! projectName@1.0.0 watch: `npm run delete; parcel watch Client/index.html --out-dir wwwroot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the projectName@1.0.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-01T17_17_44_193Z-debug.log
```

but when I run it manually, by this I mean to actually go to the terminal and type: `npm run delete; parcel watch Client/index.html --out-dir wwwroot`, it run perfectly

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: Duplicate the line, change it to your needs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a custom script to my package.json file that runs a javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433461/how-do-i-add-a-custom-script-to-my-package-json-file-that-runs-a-javascript-file)

Comment: @DarkFalcon when I call 'npm run watch' throw me an error.

Comment: Then include the error in your post. We're not mind readers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're simply missing a comma after the `delete` script.

```
{
"scripts": {
    "delete": "rm -f wwwroot/*.js wwwroot/*.css wwwroot/*.html wwwroot/*.map",
    "watch": "npm run delete; parcel watch Client/index.html --out-dir wwwroot"
  }
}
```