# How to express the array of objects via CLI?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I want to express below data via CLI parameters:

```
[
 {
    taskName: "preProcessMarkup",
    entryPointsGroups: [ "open", "admin", "emails" ]
 },
 {
    taskName: "preProcessStyles",
    entryPointsGroups: [ "open", "admin" ]
 }
]
```

It would be something like:

```
builder buildProject --taskName preProcessMarkup // ... here goes the 
// related with task "preProcessMarkup"
```

Please teach me the **correct syntax** or suggest the alternatives.

### Notes

- This question **not** about how to parse commands. This question about **how to write** commands.
- My application is being written by Node.js. I don't know how far CLI syntax is unified.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args

Comment: @bravemaster, thank you for the comment. I'am sorry for asked what I want enough clearly. I want to know how to write such command, not how to parse it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433461/how-do-i-add-a-custom-script-to-my-package-json-file-that-runs-a-javascript-file

Comment: Your post needs more detail

Comment: @bravemaster, please tell me which details are required and I'll add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$ builder buildProject --taskName preProcessMarkup --entryPointsGroup open --entryPointsGroup admin --entryPointsGroup emails --taskName preProcessStyles --entryPointsGroup open --entryPointsGroup admin
```

and parsing it;

or something accepting comma separated lists, something like:

```
$ builder buildProject --taskName preProcessMarkup --entryPointsGroups open,admin,emails --taskName preProcessStyles --entryPointsGroups open,admin
```

and again parsing it;

but I would suggest to follow the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and doing something like:

```
$ builder buildProject '[{"taskName":"preProcessMarkup","entryPointsGroups":["open","admin","emails"]},{"taskName":"preProcessStyles","entryPointsGroups":["open","admin"]}]'
```

and then parsing it simply with a `JSON.parse`.