# How to run Angular PWA directly on http-server? files throw 404 not found

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa, angularbuild

So, I have tried making a fresh new angular app work with the PWA capabilities that Angular provides, but all I get is 404 when I try to access my PWA app.
I have read hundreds of posts both here and on other sites, with no luck.

**What do I want?**

-Run a fresh new angular project and add the pwa package through angular cli

**What have I done so far?**

-I have done everything according to the angular docs. I made a new project on angular 17 with the cli command: `ng new myProject`, where I pressed "yes" when being asked if I wanted to add routing. Without altering anything, I just added pwa capabilities through the command `ng add @angular/pwa` . This did indeed add all needed files such as webmanifest, icons etc. and did alter some files just like it is supposed to.
Then, without doing ANY changes at all, I built the project with `ng build`. Then at last, I ran the server like this: `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 -o dist/`

**What is then the problem?**

When the server runs and I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/dist/` I am met with a page that says: **Index of /dist/** and it list some files. When I then click on the folder "myProject", **five network calls fail with 404 not found** and I am met with a blank page...

**What have I tried in order to fix this?**

*Many things!* First I did try it with angular 17, but I suspected it could be a problem with the new angular version, so I tried with angular 16. Same problem! I have tried running the http server differently, with npx, without the parameters, without specifying port... Same problem! Then I read that you would need the project to be built with production, so I tried with `ng build --configuration="production"`, still no cigar... I tried building inside the src folder, outside the src folder... Same problem. I tried running the http server on the project root, further down inside the dist/...Still no cigar!!
I feel I have tried everything, and it seems like my project(s) just won't work with the PWA stuff. ng serve works, but then of course without the much needed functionality from PWA.

**Details:**

- Angular cli version 16/17
- Node version 20 with angular 17, node 18 with 16
- Using Chrome v120(quite new)
- Windows 10, also tried on another computer with win11, same problem
- Using the command-line tool cmder(I don't believe this affects the problem)
- See screenshots for more info

**What do **I** think the problem is?**

I think it might have something to do with folder structure. It says 404 not found on several of these files, so I think it somehow cannot find these files...
But why? I can understand how this should not work out of the box when I just made a ng new, ng add pwa, ng build and then serve, **without doing any other changes at all.**

Thanks so much in advance to those who want to help me. I have tried everything I can in order to make this work, but I only came so far...

[image: serving]
[image: How it looks localhost]
[image: network tab when entering keyProject]
[image: dev console when entering keyProject]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TLDR; http-server path should match the build base-href

- **Quick Solution**: Add `base-href` param, like this `ng build --base-href=/dist/key-project/browser/`
- **Recommendation**: Do not use `http-server`. Instead, deploy in a proper web application server, look for more details [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration). Also, for development use `ng serve`. As a side note, the [documentation you provided](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#service-worker-in-action-a-tour) for service workers is not updated as it doesnt's considers the latest dist folder structure. It might work for really old versions of Angular.

---

There's two issues with steps you described, when using `ng build`, you'll get this folder structure:

```
// Note: in old versions of angular, folders `key-project` and `browser` are not 
// created, `index.html` would be a direct child of `dist`.

dist
 └── key-project
      └── browser
           └── index.html
```

1. That folder structure is not meant to be "seen" directly from a webserver because in order to open your app you'll need to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/dist/key-project/browser` **(the issue is caused by this)**
2. You're building your app with no name, the deployment name can be set with the `--base-href` parameter

You can check by yourself by looking at your compilled `index.html` source file, you'll see this line:

```html
<base href="/">
```

**That line means that all the internal js/css/etc files that your application needs must be inside that relative path to your server domain.**

With that in mind, if you run `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 -o dist/key-project/browser`, you'll sure be able to see your web application static content, but all the JS/CSS file references will show 404 errors because of your current folder structure. So, **you'll have to "fix" your compillation to match the one of http-server**.

---

#### Solution #1

Instead of `ng build` alone, add the `base-href` param to indicate the correct urls:

```js
// very important to keep both slashes, at start and the end
ng build --base-href=/dist/key-project/browser/
```

With that, you'll get this for your base href:

```html
<base href="/dist/key-project/browser/">
```

After that, you should be able to run `http-server` without any `404` errors:

```
npx http-server -p 8080 -c-1 -o dist/key-project/browser
```

---

#### Solution #2

Unless you're migrating an old angular application to the latest version; **this solution is not recommended**, as it basically sets the configuration back to how it was before the angular default `build` changes, the configuration is done inside your `angular.json` file, this are the attributes you should set:

```js
// Note: This configuration, basically removes `ssr` and `ssg` capabilities.
{
  "projects": {
     "architect": {
        "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser", // <-- Modify
        "build": {
          "options": {
             "outputPath": "dist",                          // <-- Modify
             "main": "src/main.ts",                         // <-- Add
             "baseHref": "/dist/"                           // <-- Add
             // "browser": "src/main.ts",                   // <-- Remove
             // "server": "src/main.server.ts",             // <-- Remove
             // "prerender": true,                          // <-- Remove
             // "ssr": "..."                                // <-- Remove
             ...
          },
          "configurations": {
             "production": {
                 "serviceWorker": true,                     // <-- Modify
                 ...                     
             }
             ...
          },
          ...
        }
        ...
     } 
  }
}
```

After those changes, **you should be able to execute exactly the steps mentioned in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#service-worker-in-action-a-tour):**

```
// (1) build directly
ng build
// (2) run http-server directly
npx http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/
```

---

Alternatively, for development is preferred that you use `ng serve` and only for production set the `base-href` value, as those builds are meant to be deployed, usually in production you won't have to navigate that whole path, so it'll do to just set it to `--base-href=key-project`

Comment: Thank you so much! Amazing!
How come Angular haven't updated the docs??
How did you find out of this?

Comment: Hi!! I did exactly what you said in your question and then solved it (the 404 error when using build is almost always related to a wrong base-href configuration). After that I noticed that your comment in @Bastian answer and took a look to it. Those steps are impossible to work with current folder structure. Also, I had worked with Angular since version 2 (beta) and I know for a fact that the folder structure wasn't like that. So it resulted obvious to me that those steps were meant for older Angular versions. After that, I updated my answer referencing those changes.

Comment: Great! One final thing: Can the base href be set in the index.html or start_url? So that I do not need to always build with the base href option?

Comment: You have to always set the `base-href` option to `ng build`, if you don't want to type it, I recommend that you [add a custom command to your package.json file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41899945/1657465), that way you would just run that, something like `npm start-build`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 -o dist/` is interpreting `dist/` as the value to the `-o` parameter. So your command should look like this:

```
http-server -p 8080 -c-1 -o / dist/key-project/browser
```

Or you can provide the path before the other parameters and skip the value for `-o`:

```
http-server dist/key-project/browser -p 8080 -c-1 -o
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not do any difference. When I run that command, I get "page not found". I run my command according how the angular docs say I should. https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

Comment: @Koen, the documentation link you provided is not updated as it doesn't considers new stuff generated at [`build`](https://angular.io/cli/build) (folders, ssg, ssr) nor the latest build parameters